# How to extract appropriate data in Plotly Grouped Bar Chart?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, bar-chart, plotly-python

Well, I am trying to plot a Bar Graph in Plotly where I need to show 3 years of data in a grouped bar chart though the chart is  displaying the data  in the chart not showing data correctly all the bars are equal in the graph Something like this:
[image]

Here is my code for plotting:

```
data=[go.Bar(x=nasdaq['Sector'],y=recent_ipos['IPO Year'],textangle=-45,name='2015'),
go.Bar(x=nasdaq['Sector'],y=recent_ipos['IPO Year'],textangle=-45,name='2016'),
go.Bar(x=nasdaq['Sector'],y=recent_ipos['IPO Year'],textangle=-45,name='2017')
]

layout=go.Layout(title="NASDAQ Market Capitalization IPO yEAR (million USD)",barmode='group')
fig=go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
fig.show(renderer="colab")
```

Here is my code which I am using to extract the data for 3 years:

```
recent_ipos = nasdaq[nasdaq['IPO Year'] > 2014]
recent_ipos['IPO Year'] = recent_ipos['IPO Year'].astype(int)
```

I tried to extract the 2015 data here using an array but I don't find an appropriate method here to extract an element from the array

```
ipo2015=np.array(recent_ipos['IPO Year'])
ipo2015
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to extract the particular year data or not??
Things I want to know here are :

How to extract year data appropriately in the graph using Plotly?

What changes I should make to solve this inconsistency in the graph?

What should I put in Y= in all the three groups bars??

How to extract the years dynamically rather than manually?

Hope to receive help from this amazing community on StackOverflow.
Thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the code under the assumption that the data on which the question is based is in data frame format. The data is taken from plotly. The query() can also be used as a variable using @ as shown in the code.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

# yyyy = [1992,1997,2002]
df = px.data.gapminder()
continent = df['continent'].unique().tolist()
yyyy = df['year'].unique().tolist()[-3:] # update
data = []
for y in yyyy:
    # tmp_df = df.query('year == @y')
    tmp_df = df[df['year'] == y].groupby('continent')['pop'].sum()
    data.append(go.Bar(x=tmp_df.index, y=tmp_df, name=y))
    
# Change the bar mode
fig = go.Figure(data)
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want the years to extract manually I want to extract years dynamically !! Even i come across the similar code on plotly official documentation but this doesn't  fulfil my requirement!!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by getting the year to your intended dynamic?

Comment: I mean currently, my requirement is for three years but my data will keep updating for coming years as I will be directly getting live data by connecting with web servers so to sort this I looking to fulfil the condition as I mentioned above instead of using the yyyy which has some specific years already!!

Comment: To deal with the situation where you always want to get the latest three years, you can get the unique year data and make a list. Then use the slice function to get the three values from the end. The code has been updated.